# Modify table creation date

Tags: sql-server-2005

Is it possible to modify the table creation date of a table? The date which we see on right clicking a `table > properties > Created date` or in `sys.tables.create_date`.

Even though the tables were created months ago, I want it to look like they were created today.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: to fool my college in to believing that i have made the database from scratch...well they kind of check the dates etc. don't want to build the complete database again

Answer (score 1):

No more than you can change your birthday, and why would you want to  ?

You could just

```
select * into #tmp from [tablename]
drop table [tablename]
select * into [tablename] from #tmp
```

That would rebuild the table and preserve the structure (to a point). You could script a new table , copy data then drop and rename. As above.

Comment: I like the birthday analogy. and a +1 for something that may work (so long as they wanted to change it to today)

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2000, you could do this by hacking into the system tables with the sp_configure option 'allow updates' set to 1.

This is not possible in SQL Server 2005 and up. From Books Online:

> This option is still present in the sp_configure stored procedure,
>   although its functionality is unavailable in Microsoft SQL Server 2005
>   (the setting has no effect). In SQL Server 2005, direct updates to the
>   system tables are not supported.

In 2005 I believe you could "game the system" by using a [dedicated administrator connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189595.aspx), but I think that was fixed shortly after RTM (or it needs a trace flag or some other undocumented setting to work). Even using DAC and with the sp_configure option set to 1, trying this on both SQL Server 2005 SP4 and SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 yields:

```
 Msg 259, Level 16, State 1 
 Ad hoc updates to system catalogs are not allowed.
```

Who are you trying to fool, and why?

**EDIT**

Now that we have more information on the why, you could create a virtual machine that is not attached to any domain, set the clock back to whatever date you want, create a database, create your objects, back up the database, copy it to the host, and restore it. The `create_date` for those objects should still reflect the earlier date, though the database itself might not (I haven't tested this).

You can do this by shifting the clock back on your own system, but I don't know if I'd want to mess with my clock this way after SQL Server has been installed and has been creating objects in what will become "the future" for a short period of time. VM definitely seems safer to me.

Comment: my professor of course because i am lazy and a procrastinator ;)

Comment: Oh, I think I misunderstood. You want the professor to think you created the database today, not that you had been working on it all along. I'll leave my modified answer as is in case someone comes along wanting to make their tables look *older* rather than *newer*.